# How to use text-to-speech to read out text on Google Books

Tags: text-to-speech, accessibility, google-play-books

I would like to know the exact steps a visually impaired or blind person would take to

1. Download a book called "X" from the Google Play store
2. Enable text-to-speech for their language (e.g. Zulu) on their device.
3. Have it read aloud from the Google Play app.

Answer (score 0):

*When you're in the app:*
Settings button > Read aloud.

Make sure to keep the volume high enough to be heard